# Authenticating User actions with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

I am using Twitter Omniauth and would like to set up before_actions in my controllers to authenticate user actions and restrict users form editing, updating, and deleting other user posts just like devise authenticate_user! method allows. How can I define this in omniauth since it is not built in?

Comment: You can implement your own method in Application Controller, and use it like you do with authenticate_user!.

Comment: I know but what is the set up currently i have:  def authenticate_user!
     redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def user_signed_in?
     !!session[:user_id]
  end

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, you can adapt to your needs.

In your ApplicationController :

```
def require_signin!
 if current_user.nil?
  flash[:error] = "Please sign in..."
  redirect_to signin_url
 end
end
helper_method :require_signin!

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

And use `require_signin!` like you use `authenticate_user!`.

Comment: how would require_signin! they way you have defined it stop other users from being able to edit, delete, and update information not pertaining to them?

Comment: require_signin! acts like authenticate_user! It prevents no logged-in user to do action : before_action :require_signin!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy].                      To prevent editing content from another user, you can check if your post belongs to current_user with current_user method.